# Resizing a drawable issue (a reference not being passed?)

Tags: java, android, drawable

In the game I'm developing I needed to resize drawables so I found a piece of code that does what I want. Let's say I want to resize everything to ButtonWidth/2, ButtonHeight/2 for the sake of simplicity. Here's the code:

```
Drawable ResizeDrawable(Drawable image)
{
     Bitmap temp = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();
     Bitmap resbit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, ButtonWidth/2, ButtonHeight/2, true);
     Drawable ret = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resbit );
     return ret;
}
```

Later on, I discovered that this procedure leaks memory (the "return" line specifically) so I changed this method to void:

```
void ResizeDrawable(Drawable image)
{
     temp = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();
     resbit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, ButtonWidth/2, ButtonHeight/2, true);
     image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resbit );
}
```

I know that Java passes references so this should work, but it doesn't. The full code that doesn't work:

```
//Variables are declared globally
Bitmap temp;
Bitmap resbit;
int ButtonWidth=100, ButtonHeight=100;

void TakeCareOfButtons() //I call this from OnCreate()
{
   MyDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mydrawableresource);
   ResizeDrawable(MyDrawable);
}
void ResizeDrawable(Drawable image)
{
     temp = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();
     resbit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, ButtonWidth/2, ButtonHeight/2, true);
     image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resbit );
}
```

So the first thing I did was remove the method completely, and just manually resize every drawable,just to see if it works. And it did. The code that works:

```
//Variables are declared globally
Bitmap temp;
Bitmap resbit;
int ButtonWidth=100, ButtonHeight=100;//not the real values, but it's irrelevant now


    void TakeCareOfButtons() //I call this from OnCreate()
    {
         MyDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mydrawableresource);
         temp = ((BitmapDrawable) MyDrawable).getBitmap();
         resbit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, ButtonWidth/2, ButtonHeight/2, true);
         MyDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resbit );
    }
```

**The question is:** Aren't the two codes equivalent? Shouldn't they do the same thing in Java?

Note: By "works" I mean "does resize". I can view on the screen if the drawable has been resized or not.

Comment: Java passes *references by value* so `image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resbit);` in your first example changes what the *local* reference points do, making your code essentially "do nothing".

Comment: Oh, thanks. So if I want to resize 20 drawables is there a better thing to do than just copy the same code 20 times?

Comment: Passing an array containing your Drawables to that method, and then looping through should work. What causes the return statement to leak memory however? I'd say it's something else related to the Drawables themselves.

Comment: Yeah, of course that would work, but my drawables are not in an array so putting them there would require copying, and I wanna avoid that. I will find a workaround, that's not important now. Thanks for the support, write it as an answer so I can upvote.

Comment: Well I don't know. I started reading about Drawables/Bitmaps leaking memory but then I realized that changing the function to void solves it. Can you explain it? The problem was that some memory was left occupied every time I close an activity. So restarting a single player game around 15 times would cause a crash.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. A very dumb one. The "second" code (the void function that "does nothing") doesn't overflow (wonder why). But when I delete the method it still does. So I guess you're right, I still have a problem (and my method can still return Drawable). I tried to override OnDestroy in order to clear the traces from an active activity but it failed.

Comment: Drawables are not my specialty. I could guess that the Application or the System is keeping the Drawable or its bitmap in memory for some reason, but asking a new question should help you more :)

Comment: That is exactly what it does. I will study memory leaks, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the argument-passing question:

References in Java are passed by value. This means if, in a method that accepts in an Object argument and you assign a `new` object to that reference variable, like so:

```
public void doSomething (Object bar){
  bar = new Object();
}
```

And call `doSomething (myObject);`

`myObject` will *not* be modified to point to your `new Object ()`.